# Need a faster way of removing all disabled products from all categories

Tags: magento-1.8, php, category-products

We recently dropped a bunch of vendors, and need to get the disabled products out of the categories to make merchandising easier.  Also just for sanity so we don't have to keep looking at them in the category product lists.

Here is the script I came up with

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
if ($catIds){
foreach ($catIds as $id){
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $cat->load($id);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($cat)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)) //filter commented, show all products
        ->load();

    foreach ($collection as $prod) {
        var_dump("Removing product id " . $prod->getId() . " from  category " . $id);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($id,$prod->getId());

    }
}
```

}

Obviously this will take forever, since we have umpteen bazillion categories.  I need something that works like this:

Get Category
Get all disabled products, and create an array of their IDs.
Set the array of products on the category to that array of product ids.
Save the category.

Right now i'm digging through

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php
```

and

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category\Api.php
```

to find a function i might be able to use.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine. Seems like this is about as good as it gets.

```
<?php
// Instantiate magento 
umask(0);
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');

// Disable the indexers
// It will try to reindex every time a category is changed. Halts the process.
$pCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($pCollection as $process) {
    $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
    //$process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
}

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
if ($catIds){
    foreach ($catIds as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('position')
            ->addCategoryFilter($cat)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)) 
            ->load();

        $prodPositions = array();
        $existingPositions = $cat->getProductsPosition();
        foreach($collection as $product) {
            // Preserve existing position, or assign 0;                
            $prodPositions[$product->getId()] = (int)$existingPositions[$product->getId()];
        }

        $cat->setPostedProducts($prodPositions);
        $cat->save();
        var_dump("Updated Category ID " . $id);
    }
}

// Re-enable indexers
foreach ($pCollection as $process) {
    $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```